# Auto Align 3 buttons in a layout android

Tags: android

I have a relative layout which as 4 buttons. Now I am doing fill_parent for the width.
For 1st and 4th button I can do align parent left/right. But how to properly align button 2,3 so that there is a proper spacing between all buttons.

I tried doing programatically but I am not able to move or set the exact position of the button as there is a lot of logic based on pixel width and dpi.

Is there any easy way out?

Comment: Can't you use a linear layout? It's either that or setting their size at runtime which is a huge bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way out is using a `LinearLayout` with the four buttons as children, where all children have an equal `layout_weight`.

Don't forget to set the `android:layout_width` of all Buttons to "0dp".

Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That should be 4. Forgot to correct that from the copy-paste. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: weightSum is not necessary here. The parent view defaults its weightSum to the sum of weights in it. On the other hand it doesn't do any real harm. You just have to remember about adjusting it when fiddling with the number of child views and their weights.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way would be to put them in a `LinearLayout` and give each `layout_width="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"`